# Global exception handling in @Named class in spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, exception, akka

I want to handle a set of exceptions in one of the class which is annotated using `@Named`.

I am using AKKA actors for concurrency. Also using Hibernate.

In my Akka actor class, I am invoking the hibernate methods for insert operations. 
I want to know how to handle exceptions in all the actor classes globally. I can do that using `@ExceptionHandler` and `@ControllerAdvice`. But I believe that it works only in the `@Controller` layer.

Sample code is given below:

```
@Named("SaveDepartmentService") 
public class SaveDepartmentService extends BaseCommonService {

 @Autowired
 IDepartmentRepository departmentRepository;

 @Override
 public PartialFunction<Object, BoxedUnit> receive(){
    return ReceiveBuilder
            .match(Department.class, c->createOrUpdateDepartment(c))
            .build()
            .orElse(matchAny());
 }

 private void createOrUpdateDepartment(Department dept){
   // try{
         departmentRepository.insertOrUpdate(dept);
   // }catch (ConstraintViolationException e){
    //    System.out.println("-------------------------------");
     //   e.printStackTrace();
     //   wrap the exception and send as 
     //   sender().tell("Constarint_violation",self());
    //}
    sender().tell(dept, self());
 }  }
```

I want to handle `ConstraintViolationException` across my actors and respond with a message (`eg: sender().tell("CONSTRAINT_VIOLATION", self());`). 
I can do the same thing by handling it in catch block, but i need to duplicate it in all actor classes.

Is there any way to handle it like `@ControllerAdvice`?

Comment: Why are you mixing Spring MVC annotations with CDI annotations? Could you give a proper explanation of your design?

Comment: As I said, we are using akka actors. The layers are as given below:    Controllers -> Services(akka actors) -> DAO(Hibernate). When a request comes, it invokes the associated akka actor, which then query the database and return the result using the tell() of the actor

Comment: That doesn't explain why you use CDI instead of Spring MVC annotations...

Comment: It uses Akka Futures. There is time till which akka actor waits for the response. If it exceeds that, it automatically sends a timeout error. So if an database exception(say, unique key violation happens), tell() method will not be invoked and the response will not be sent back, which results in timeout erros

Comment: Again: why are you using CDI instead of Spring MVC `@Controller` that may solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [default exception handler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler)).

> By setting the default uncaught exception handler, an application can change the way in which uncaught exceptions are handled (such as logging to a specific device, or file) for those threads that would already accept whatever "default" behavior the system provided.

**But** it makes no difference between CDI-Beans and Non-CDI-Beans (By the way: I use it to automatically increase the level of logging of all classes in the Stacktraces)